# Is there a way to have Adobe Flash displayed in Android 2.0?

Tags: adobe-flash, 2.1-eclair

Are there any custom players or plug-ins or something like that?

Comment: Might be possible using Javascript as well with [Smokescreen](http://smokescreen.us/) but I have no idea if that has been realised in an app for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a few "Flash Lite" binaries floating around the net for Android 2.0.

It's not Flash, it's only a partial version with fewer features.

Unfortunately the only binary link I have is an update for the Pandigital Novel; the update is probably specifically for that model, but the binary inside may work on other devices. (If you want it, comment & I'll update my answer. It's hosted on mediafire, not adobe's website which means I'm not sure how much I trust it.)